# Can you pass an array of index numbers to the array push method instead of specifying each index in push specifically

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a new 2D array from another 2D array retaining specific columns from the original array that are defined in a variable.

I have a working version that uses hardcoded values of which columns from the original array to retain but I need a version that uses a variable.

```
var data = [
             [1,5,7,8,9,98,56],
             [4,7,8,9,2,55,88],
             [3,3,4,3,3,24,11]
            ];

 var indexes2Keep = [0,2,6]; 

 data.forEach(function(row) {
    slicedData.push( [ row[2], row[4], row[6] ] );
 });
```

Instead of having the columns hardcoded in the array push method how can I use the values of the variable indexes2Keep to give the same result.

thanks

Expected output is:

```
slicedData = [
         [1,7,56],
         [4,8,88],
         [3,4,11]
        ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.map`/`Array.filter`:

```js
var data = [
         [1,5,7,8,9,98,56],
         [4,7,8,9,2,55,88],
         [3,3,4,3,3,24,11]
        ];

var indexes2Keep = [0,2,6]; 
var slicedData = data.map(function (row){
  return row.filter(function(_,i){
     return indexes2Keep.indexOf(i) !== -1
  })
})
//Alternatively
var slicedData2 = data.map(function (row){
  return indexes2Keep.map(function(i){
     return row[i]
  })
})
console.log(slicedData)
console.log(slicedData2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply call `.map` on that array to map each index to the element at that index in the row.

```js
data.forEach(function(row) {
    slicedData.push(indexes2Keep.map(function(index) {return row[index]}));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `map()` function for this:

`slicedData.push(indexes2Keep.map(index => row[index]));`

Comment: ES6 notation is awesome - if the OP doesn't want to support legacy browsers this is a great option.

Comment: I suppose if the original code uses `var`, old fashioned `function`s might be better!